# Camel Bindy : configurable "pos" attribute in @DataField

Tags: csv, apache-camel, bindy

I am configuring my POJO to unmarshal a CSV line, so I declared my attributes as indicated on the camel-bindy official page, and everything went well when unmarshalling.

```
@DataField(pos = 1) 
private String name; 
... 
getter and setter
```

What I need to do is to make the `pos` attribute configurable, pointing a corresponding property in a properties.file to indicate the position of the `name` column in the CSV line.

Is it possible to implement such behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. And there is no plans to support this in the future.

You can take a look at some of the other CSV components such as beanio which allows to define binding information in external configuration files.

- http://camel.apache.org/beanio
- http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

Comment: Thanks Claus for your reply. beanIO could be an alternative, or we can just handle the CSV data in a decicated Processor.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know if it's possible to do with Bindy, but nothing seems to indicate it in the documentation.

What you could do when you are unsure of the position of your properties position is using the camel CSV data unmarshaling.

http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

you create a route that check for csv files in a given folder, unmarshal each csv lines to `List<String>`  and send that `List<List <String>>` to a bean of yours that will do the processing. 
Given that the first line of your csv file is the columns, in your bean you'll know the position of each attributes and you'll be able to map the csv strings of data to the attributes of your bean.

route that process file and unmarshall lines :

```
<route>
    <from uri="file:///path/where/are/my/csvfiles?delete=true />
    <unmarshal><csv /></unmarshal>
    <to uri="bean:myCsvMapper?method=doHandleCsvData" />
```

Your bean:

```
public void doHandleCsvData(List<List<String>> csvData){
   // with first line (column names) get the position of your attributes

   // for next lines do the mapping between the position and the attributes 
   // of your data bean
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fred for your reply. As bindy doesn't support this kind of feature, it makes sense to handle the CSV data manually as you mentioned.